# What is the solution of this limit with the form infinity minus infinity?

Tags: calculus

I need help to Calculate the following limit: $$\displaystyle \lim_{x \to +\infty}{x^{3/2}(\sqrt{x+1}+\sqrt{x-1}-2\sqrt{x})}$$ 
I had tried to accommodate the expression in a different way rationalizing, to apply L'Hopital's theorem, however it had results like$\displaystyle \lim_{x \to +\infty}{\frac{x^4-x^3}{\sqrt{x^4-x^3}}}+\frac{x^4-x^3}{\sqrt{x^4+x^3}}- 2x^2$.

So I couldn't find the way to apply L'Hopital and it only got more complicated.

Comment: Welcome to math.stackexchange. You might want to know that posts like yours, a bare problem statement with no context at all, quickly attract down votes and close votes. To avoid this, check out our guidelines for [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question), with emphasis on [providing context](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question#9960).

Comment: You can easily provide some context by editing your post to include what you tried, where you got stuck, and perhaps by formulating an actual mathematical question regarding your own attempts.

Comment: Hint: $(1+1/z)^k=1+k/z+k(k-1)/(2z^2)+...$ when +z+<<1$

Comment: Group together $(\sqrt{x+1}-\sqrt{x})+(\sqrt{x-1}-\sqrt{x})$. In the first parenthesis you can multiply and divide by $\sqrt{x+1}+\sqrt{x}$ and get $\frac{1}{\sqrt{x+1}+\sqrt{x}}$. Likewise, in the second parenthesis, you can multiply and divide by $\sqrt{x-1}+\sqrt{x}$ to get $\frac{-1}{\sqrt{x-1}+\sqrt{x}}$. Now, when you sum these two fractions, you get $\frac{\sqrt{x+1}-\sqrt{x-1}}{(\sqrt{x+1}+\sqrt{x})(\sqrt{x-1}+\sqrt{x})}$. This you can multiply and divide by $\sqrt{x+1}+\sqrt{x-1}$. The numerator will become $2$.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1302346/help-with-limit-of-function and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2117785/finding-the-limit-lim-n-to-inftyn3-2-sqrtn1-sqrtn-1-2-sqrtn are questions on the same limit.

Answer (score 2):

\begin{align}
&\lim_{x \to \infty} x^{3/2}(\sqrt{x+1}+\sqrt{x-1}-2\sqrt{x})
\\
&= \lim_{x \to \infty} x^2 (\sqrt{1+1/x} + \sqrt{1-1/x} - 2)
\\
&=
\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{\sqrt{1+h} - 2 \sqrt{1} + \sqrt{1-h}}{h^2}
\end{align}

This [limit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second_derivative#Limit) is the second derivative of the function $f(x)=\sqrt{1+x}$ evaluated at $x=0$.